# anchor tag seen twice in Ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone, ipad

I have created anchor tag and on click of that i just open simple popup which ask for email id to retrieve the password. Now when i click on forget password it show me forget link two times. Below is my code.

```
 <!-- login start --->

    <div class="gu_login">
        <label id="errMsg"></label>
        <p>Login</p>
        <input name="username" type="text" id="username" placeholder="USERNAME" />
        <input name="password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In" class="gu_btn" id="btnSubmit" onclick="return login();" />
        <a href="#forgot_password" id="forgotPassword">Forgot Password?</a>
    </div>

    <div class="splash fade-in" id="splashScreenForgotPassword" style="display: none; align-self: center">
         <label id="errMsgForgotPassword"></label>
        <h1 class="splash-title fade-in">
            Please Answer Security Question
        </h1>
        <div class="gu_manualformcont">
            <div class="gu_manualform">
                <label>Question</label><h1 class="floatleft martop5 width380 alignleft"><span id="securityQuestion"></span></h1></div>
            <div class="gu_manualform">
                <label>Answer</label>
                <input type="password" id="securityAnswer" placeholder="ANSWER" class="width380 height50" />
            </div>

            <div class="gu_manualform">
                <input type="button" id="BTNSave" value="Submit" onclick="VerifyAnswer();" class="btnlarge green-btn floatrightimp marleft5" />
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btnlarge red-btn floatrightimp marright5" onclick="$('#splashScreenForgotPassword').hide();" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="splash-close fade-in">
            <img src="/library/images/down-arrow.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <!-- login end --->
```

Given is code for JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#username").focus();
            $('a[href="#forgot_password"]').click(function () {
                if ($("#username").val().length > 0) {
                    try {
                        var retVal = "";
                        $("#errMsg").text('');
                        $("#errMsg").removeClass("error");
                        var urlCreate = "login.aspx?method=ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestion&userName=" + String($("#username").val());
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: urlCreate,
                            contentType: "text/plain",
                            dataType: "",
                            success: function (response) {
                                //alert(response);
                                if (String(response).length >= 0) {

                                    if (response.indexOf('not found') > 0) {
                                        ShowError(response);
                                    }
                                    else {

                                        var returnVal = response.split("|");
                                        var re = new RegExp('_', 'g');
                                        $('#securityQuestion').text((returnVal[1]).replace(re," ") + "?");

                                        securityAnswer = returnVal[2];
                                        userID = returnVal[0];
                                        ShowSplashScreen("splashScreenForgotPassword");
                                    }
                                }
                                else {

                                    ShowError("error occurred while processing your request");
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                ShowError(response);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        alert("Catch" + err);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    ShowError("Please enter user name");
                }
            });
        });
```

Given is Screenshot of IPad for the Error.
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTvvO.png)

Comment: Can you also post your entire HTML code?

Comment: @DavidR Please See it now.

Comment: Do you manipulate the `#forgot_password` selector id in any of your functions like `ShowError` (or) `ShowSplashScreen` etc?

Comment: @DavidR I have not Manipulate it, I have posted my entire code there is nothing more than this.

Comment: @Freelancer One last request, can you please post your CSS file too?

Comment: It is not accepted here. So i can not post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122995/discussion-between-david-r-and-freelencer).